# How can I 'pad out' a CSV file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example suppose I wish for a CSV file with 5 columns.  How could I convert

```
a,b,c,d
d,e,f
```

into

```
a,b,c,d,
d,e,f,,
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy in Awk:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{$5=$5}1'
```

Not too hard in Bash:

```
IFS=,
while read -a F; do
    for ((i=0; i<5; i++)); do
        F[i]=${F[i]}
    done
    echo "${F[*]}"
done
```

Comment: @php-coder `{$5=$5}` ensures there are at least 5 fields and forces Awk to recompute `$0` by joining all fields with `OFS`.  `1` is an always-true condition with no body, so the body defaults to `{print}`, which outputs `$0`.

Answer (score 4):

Example with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '{printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5)}' example.txt
a,b,c,d,
d,e,f,,
```

or

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' example.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^([^,]*)(,|)([^,]*)(,|)([^,]*)(,|)([^,]*)(,|)$/\1,\3,\5,\7,/'

#             |          |          |          |          ^  ^  ^  ^
#             |          |          |          |          |  |  |  |
#             |__________|__________|__________|__________|  |  |  |
#                        |__________|__________|_____________|  |  |
#                                   |__________|________________|  |
#                                              |___________________|
```

Proof:

```
echo -e "a,b,c,d\nd,e,f\nx" | sed -r 's/^([^,]*)(,|)([^,]*)(,|)([^,]*)(,|)([^,]*)(,|)$/\1,\3,\5,\7,/'
a,b,c,d,
d,e,f,,
x,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which I like very much is this:

```
gawk '{print $0 ",,,,,"}' a | cut -d \, -f 1-5
```

I think it is much more simple and clear

Comment: It also truncates at 5 fields if there were more to start with.  Sometimes okay and sometimes not, depending on what it's being used for.